# How to make input text field to accept only specific special character - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to restrict the input text field to accept only specific special characters and also the special character should not be the first character.

I have tried but could not able to find a solution for this problem.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.value" required="required" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^]*$/"/>
```

Comment: `accept only special chars and they should not be first` contradicts each other. please provide example what should be accepted and what not

Answer (score 0):

Given your attempt, I believe you want only A-Z, a-z and 0-9 for the first character, and after that, you want all characters except A-Z, a-z and 0-9.

The regex/ng-pattern for this is `^[a-zA-Z\d]+[^a-zA-Z\d]*$`

So the field will be

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputField" required="required" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\d]+[^a-zA-Z\d]*$/"/>
```

Comment: It is accepting special character as first character.

Comment: Just some calcification: did you want it so the User cannot enter a special character or that the validation triggered?